# SQL using between syntax to validate alpha numeric values

Tags: sql, string, db2, character, between

I have 2 tables, Table1 has address ranges, Table2 has exact addresses.  All fields in both tables are char.  I need to identify the addresses in Table2 that fall between the house number ranges in Table1.  Please see below for example.  I have a join on Street, City, State and HSE# between LOW and HIGH.  The results bring back both the 1201 - 1214 and 101 - 126 TABLE1 records.  Casting the values as integers doesn't work because some addresses contain alpha characters....101B as the house number for example.  Can you help determine the best, most accurate way to accomplish this?

Table1

```
LOW     HIGH    STREET    CITY    STATE
101     126     A ST      MYCITY  MYSTATE
1201    1214    A ST      MYCITY  MYSTATE
```

TABLE2

```
HSE#      STREET    CITY    STATE
1203      A ST      MYCITY  MYSTATE

SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 A,
     TABLE2 B
WHERE B.STATE = A.STATE
  AND B.CITY = A.CITY
  AND B.STREET = A.STREET
  AND B.HSE# BETWEEN A.LOW AND A.HIGH;
```

This brings back both the TABLE1 records in the example below.  The expect result is that I only get the TABLE1 value with a LOW/HIGH range of 1201/1214 as this is truly the range the house number falls in.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Hi Jarlh - Im using DB2.

Comment: I updated - hopefully that is more along the lines of how it should be posted?

Comment: Your query returns 1 row only, with all columns from table1 and table2 (since you do `select *`.)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (Do they really teach those comma separated, implicit joins in 2020?!? I shake my head.)

Comment: I'd suggest removing the alpha characters and converting to integer.  Even if 101 has been converted into 101A and 101B, it would still fall between 100 and 105.  But that's only for single alpha suffixes...it gets lots more complicated... https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28ape_003.htm

Comment: What’s your Db2 version and platform? Is it ok for you, if I provide you a way to convert any string to a number removing any non-digit character from it, which may be used for conversion of all 3 strings participating in the BETWEEN predicate?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein - yes that would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as is:

```
SELECT A.LOW, A.HIGH, B.HSE#
FROM
(
VALUES 
  ('101B', '126')
, ('1201', '1214')
) A (LOW, HIGH)
JOIN (VALUES '1203') B(HSE#)
ON 
INT(NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(B.HSE#, '[^0-9]', ''), ''))
BETWEEN 
INT(NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.LOW,  '[^0-9]', ''), ''))
AND
INT(NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.HIGH, '[^0-9]', ''), ''));
```

The result is:

```
|LOW |HIGH|HSE#|
|----|----|----|
|1201|1214|1203|
```